# Adding Link To ResourceList Item in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-app-bridge

I have created Shopify App for Testing purpose.

[image]

As shown in the above image, i have shown products in Resource List.

```
    const productItems = useMemo( () => {
    return products.map(
        ({ id, title, featuredImage }) => ({
            id,
            title:title,
            url:`products/${extractIdFromGid(id)}`,
            icon: <Thumbnail size="small" source={featuredImage?.originalSrc || ImageMajor}/>
        })
    );
}, [products] );
```

Each Resource List Item has URL link to custom product detail page.

```
export function extractIdFromGid(gid) {
return gid.split("/").pop();}
```

But the URL redirection not working?